# Safety circuit to prevent accidents in golf carts with lithium battery packs

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, circuit-design, relay, latching-relay

I'm a hobbyist / software guy trying to solve an real problem in the very large and active golf cart community. I'm out of my element here, so I'm hope for a viable and good start.

### The issue

Thousands of golf carts are equipped with an electromagnetic motor brake (EMB), that is basically an electromagnet and a spring. When the EMB is energized, the magnet pulls the brake open so the cart can roll freely, and if power is lost, the spring snaps it shut locking up the motor/tires. It only has two positions (`on`/`off`) and nothing in between.

They also have mechanical disc brakes which are used for your normal braking. The EMB is used to prevent the cart rolling, like an auto parking brake. The controller detects the electric motor is stopped for ~1 second then engages the EMB to hold the cart's position. When you press the accelerator, you hear an audible click (EMB releasing), and then the cart drives freely.

I've already tried manually disabling the EMB in hopes of connecting it with a toggle switch for use as a parking brake, but the cart became almost undrivable with it rolling everywhere; so it does serve an important function to normal driving.

Owners are now replacing their lead acid batteries with **lithium packs**, and periodically the pack's BMS (battery management system) will have an "event" - overheating, bad cell, overcharge from regen braking, etc. - that will shut down the pack and cut power to the cart.

If the cart is traveling at speed, it can lock the tires up and **launch people from the cart or even flip the cart.**

The cart's controller turns the EMB on/off during normal operation, such as if you're on an incline at a stop light and need to preserve the normal operation.

### Proposed solution

My idea is a secondary, small lead-acid battery in a circuit with a latching relay that will only turn off with (main power `on` + key `off`). That way, the secondary battery can keep the EMB open if there is a power loss and can only be disconnected by the main power signal.

[Here is a link to an interactive version of my initial circuit.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgrCAMB0l3ECMMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxGxXHEnAFMBaRRAKEQzxABZjCR2+YYlQEg+iKNCopo2UvIWkwYQtkmQk8eOum0YkRBH0b+LAEogUKLv0K1RiO1GddaXTnslgWAD25cIFFxuQkDsNRtEKgBpOgBPFgB3bl5+DD4uRzS+SCTuLLROTPF0qBYAc3BhS3wq6WtnXIBnfL5ClLbazwAzAEMAGya6FgA3MRVLDCocNqnG7jcPRuhvZKERao5I6tz2ThnJqjxKQ7F+SSomWVISYi5CQi4ubDsc2E0tPVhddUN1E1YlQOuBswJejTyx2keE4eEelhhZWScJsKERKMsDV2HHAaIoaDEDUotHEF3+cC4GHkkFcBmIiBuWX0Hy0OhqvyMsBMzUxkScVlRWOcfUGwzW1UctHW-DxuXFIjxiCeMo8eSVkUVyuwYCouUqhCJOsJNheSz1uM4xItFBpEOSBpNttCs11bANIGEnHV-DgXuVVAAJnQ+gBXfoAFwY-ToAfOnn0rGR8IFIC2vKRqbw22mWfTcpAUJtNgxIIzJdtGLRqr81nsuewGCQeHIGpAgFBqQDwfwAFABOdCaTQAOk0ABZ0PvD8MAe2HTQAlgBbMO9cNi63akRao25GtUmq0cKdCIykAAByniXHw-6U4HeRTKeKed8llCr7c7qIx6iIF7-aHTQANbxLOiRzuGADGI6TjOTQAEThiGPYAHZwZOY7DsBcTDoALJQdnkT6PgUXQvg8nDWOQUzkCgYBuCeUQjMOABGK6rj2CRMWIrjpo2agoGQZR+IQzC2BIVL2PCradgAKiOc4AX2-S9NhTRTiG4anupw6JGp-QBsxdDDgxeRpgyRzwmZZYWdUGLevmtnKp6-DKuayC1N6bleqUegvlMEB4LQZCwt+VCyfJw4ADIAKIACLDn2p59kMyHhgB4YYU0UUALIAELQJFsXDnBU6ocOC50L0yFNL5-E+nwZASMgxDcCe2U5cO4VNOel59vpTSVX1TE9r0wHDgAcgA8tJw50Mh5S9OUMbDoA4NT4TWYARJAggbQszWtmFAHIXQMZpbBTGGf1w6aaK8V0EpKlTj2s5TuV6VznNz3aWOyHocMNbHNweLSs8EitlhHUAVO3TdMOg6nmVvTvVdF5Xv1EHhnOIwXW9Cl3cpEPIQA5OGw5Tqes3DtYAD0GDDoAvBuAGI7LBAA)

[image: Main power (on); Key (on)]

[image: Main power (on); Key (off)]

[image: Main power (off); Key (on) - Simulted Power Loss]

### Questions / Challenges

- Could this work or are there obvious issues?
- My solution uses the NC output of a relay (`R1`) to signal another relay (`R2`) to disconnect the secondary battery, but I can't figure out the logic to disconnect `R2` so it doesn't remain energized.
- Is there a better way to design the circuit or a more elegant solution?
- I realize the circuit is omitting things and currently doesn't allow normal EMB operation.
- What other mistakes have I made?

Comment: The title of your question is a little amusing - "launching people with lithium battery packs". It might benefit from some word reordering. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Can you not just add an appropriately-tuned mechanical damper to the EMB that will make auto-braking more gradual? I consider that more reliable than adding a second battery+circuit that can also fail.

Comment: The broader problem is that in the name of safety, sometimes a driver will _need to break_ at a level that could impose significant force on the driver in order to stop in time and avoid collision. How do you distinguish between deliberate rapid braking and accidental rapid braking?

Comment: In your diagram, where is the pedal input?

Comment: Pardon the title wording. An important thing to clarify (and I'll edit in post) is there are mechanical disc brakes that do your normal stopping. The controller handles the EMB and it's either `on`/`off` and nothing in between. I think the controller detects the motor is stopped for ~1 second, then engages the EMB assuming you are stopped somewhere. When you press the pedal, the EMB disengages and the motor spins.

Comment: The EMB acts as a parking brake. I manually disabled it completely and the cart was almost undrivable and was rolling all over the place, so it does serve an important function. I had hoped I could just bypass it with a switch and use it purely for a parking brake.

Comment: How about using the voltage generated by the motor to sense that the cart is still moving?  This may or may not generate enough power to hold the EMB open, so a secondary battery might still be needed.  And perhaps use FETs rather than relays since the energy required to hold these in either state is extremely low.  You could use a microcontroller to oversee the whole process at the cost of a few microamps.

Comment: @Frog - that might be a genius idea. Would the motor still generate voltage if the cart were driving UP an incline, being powered by the lithium, then the pack overheated and cut off? The core idea is the EMB should never engage while the motor is spinning, so perhaps a super simple circuit is possible?

Comment: making mods to the golf carts can put you on the receiving end of a lawsuit should something happen that causes personal injury or property damage

Comment: @jsotola - No more than modifying your own personal car. Not sure the point here. I have a legal background.

Comment: @Alex Kwitny yes the motor would generate a negative voltage when going backwards so it should be easy to identify this situation and apply the EMB as soon as the vehicle stops or changes direction.  However, another situation would be on a downhill slope where the car runs away, you’d rely on either the driver using the manual brake or an alternative that Reindarian suggested where the EMB is applied progressively.  I’m not sure I agree with their assertion that a mechanical solution is more reliable than an electrical one though.